# Connect rails application to SQL Server 2005 from Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, odbc

I *(sadly)* have to deploy a **rails** application on Windows XP which has to connect to **Microsoft SQL Server 2005**.

Surfing in the web there are a lot of hits for connect from Linux to SQL Server, but cannot find out how to do it from Windows.

Basically I followed these steps:

- Install *dbi* gem
- Install *activerecord-sql-server-adapter* gem

My **database.yml** now looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: test_dj
  host: HOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS
  database: test_dj
  username: guest
  password: guest
```

But I'm unable to connect it. When I run *rake db:migrate* I get

```
IM002 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I'm not a Windows user, so cannot understand really well the meaning of **dsn** element or so.
Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

*Thanks in advance*

---

With Alexander tips now I've modified my database.yml to:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SCADA\SQLEXPRESS;UID=guest;PWD=guest;Initial Catalog=test_dj;Application Name=test
```

But now *rake db:migrate* returns me:

```
S1090 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

this is a sample DSN, that connects to the database using the Windows user account (best when corporate network with domain login)

`Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServer\MyInstance;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Application Name=My Application Name that will show up in the trace`

So this uses the OLEDB provider for SQL Server. SQLNCLI can also be used, haven't tried it with ODBC. Actually this DSN isn't quite tested (have to wait for my admin to give me the necessary rights), but it was copied from a working script, that used SQLNCLI as the provider. The Data source is the server, and if it has a named instance, it has to be specified, so it's either just `Server`  or `Server\Instance`. The `Integrated Security=SSPI` tells it you want to use Windows Authentication. Otherwise you specify the user and password to use using `UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPassword`. UID, User, Username, Password - I think all of these parameters work.

There is a great site over the internet that provides all kinds of DSN samples, just can't find it anywhere. If I find it, I will let you know.

If you haven't got any provider in Rails, check out if Rails supports Windows Component Object Model (COM). And if it does, you can even initialize the ADODB.Connection COM class, work with ADO thereon.

Ah, here is that site I was talking about: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your answer. According to your tip I've modified my database.yml as in the edited post, but now having "Invalid string or buffer length"

Comment: This looks like an error in the SQL queries already, not a connection error. It's helpful to provide the error code also, it may say a lot.
Anyway, I found this article that might help you out:
http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/why-do-i-get-80040e57/80040e07-errors.html
of course, it depends on what scale your SQL queries are automated and how you are able to modify them. Also keep in mind that the CHAR and VARCHAR in MSSQL have a maximum length of 8000.

Comment: I have the same problem as Enrico. Here is the error: 

ODBC::Error: S1090 (0) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

This is from doing an all query on my (very simple) model.

Comment: http://lists.mysql.com/myodbc/1369 ?
it's mysql but this could also apply to MSSQL

Comment: Maybe need to set this higher?  'raw_connection_do "SET TEXTSIZE #{64.megabytes}" ' - taken from here https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#configure-connection--app-name