# Database configuration file for Sql server on windows

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the configuration of database.yml file for sql server in windows.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806584/rails-sql-server-what-to-put-in-database-yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: test_dj
  host: HOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS
  database: test_dj
  username: guest
  password: guest
```